# How does scaling operator (*) work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, geometry, gis

I just started learning PostgreSQL and I cannot figure out how does scaling operator work on geometric types.

For example `select '((1, 1), (0, 0))'::box * '(2, 0)'::point;` returns `((2,2),(0,0))`

and `select '((1, 1), (0, 0))'::box * '(0, 2)'::point;` returns `((0,2),(-2,0))`

so in both cases box gets scaled by the factor of 2 (for both axes), but the way box is moved makes no sense to me.

[Official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) only shows one example of usage of this operator and nothing about how it works.

If someone knows a better resource for learning PostgreSQL please share it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this Matrix x Vector multiplication? If box is 2x2 Matrix and point is vector of size 2 (2x1 Matrix) multiplying these two should give 2x1 Matrix (which cannot be box)

Comment: Documentation says it is "scaling/rotation" so maybe (magnitude,radians)

Comment: As to "a better resource" maybe try a few examples and it may become obvious.

Comment: e.g. maybe it is treated as a diagonal matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is implementation of the function `box_mul` that stays behind the `*(box, point)` operator (from https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/geo_ops.c):

```
static inline void
point_mul_point(Point *result, Point *pt1, Point *pt2)
{
    point_construct(result,
                    float8_mi(float8_mul(pt1->x, pt2->x),
                              float8_mul(pt1->y, pt2->y)),
                    float8_pl(float8_mul(pt1->x, pt2->y),
                              float8_mul(pt1->y, pt2->x)));
}

Datum
box_mul(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    BOX        *box = PG_GETARG_BOX_P(0);
    Point      *p = PG_GETARG_POINT_P(1);
    BOX        *result;
    Point       high,
                low;

    result = (BOX *) palloc(sizeof(BOX));

    point_mul_point(&high, &box->high, p);
    point_mul_point(&low, &box->low, p);

    box_construct(result, &high, &low);

    PG_RETURN_BOX_P(result);
}
```

or translated to the more "human" language:

`((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) * (x, y) :- ((x1*x - y1*y, x1*y + y1*x), (x2*x - y2*y, x2*y + y2*x))`

For your example

`((1,1),(0,0)) * (0,2) = ((1*0 - 1*2, 1*2 + 1*0), (0*0 - 0*2, 0*2 + 0 * 0)) = ((-2,2),(0,0))`

and finally `box_construct()` transforms it to `(0,2),(-2,0)` (just check `select '((-2,2),(0,0))'::box;`)

If you know/remember the geometric meaning of those transformations - post your final answer here.